# Oracle APEX: Query is fast but load the page is very slow

Tags: oracle-apex

I use Oracle APEX. When users want to show page "X", it take long time, but when i execute query of page in some tools like Navicat, it executed fast.
how can i handle this problem? 
I think, it may be users request was lot on the page...
  TNX.

Comment: Without further information it's hard to help.

Comment: Please provide debug information with timings on client and server.

Comment: Can run the page in debug mode and see exactly what process is taking up the time.

Comment: See this: http://www.laureston.ca/2019/12/05/15-top-tips-to-tune-your-oracle-apex-performance/ Look at #4. Then give us more details.

Answer (score 0):

It solved. I ran the page in debug mode and saw exactly what process is taking up the time. 
Thank you all.